# Combining object arrays ({a:a,b:b, c:c},{a:a,d:d,c:c}) to ({a:a,b:c,d:c})

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a list of data that I'm getting that I need to convert and "pivot" to turn one column into multiple columns.

The list of objects I have looks like this:

```
var list = [
{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 10
},
{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "run",
    "value": 8
},
{
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "delete",
    "value" : 2
},
{
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 5
},
]
```

I need to convert this for a charting library so that it looks like this:

```
var list = [
{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "test": 10,
    "run": 8,
    "delete": 0
},
{
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "test": 5,
    "run": 0,
    "delete": 2
}
]
```

Is there a fairly easy way to do this using underscore.js functions like _.groupBy and _.map etc...?

Comment: Mapping criteria isn't totally intuitive without explanation

Comment: The example in the question title maps properties/values that exist in the input array. The full example in the question body creates properties that aren't in the original array, like adding `delete` to the 2016-05-31 date. What would you expect to happen if more than `test` property were defined for the same date?

Comment: I've done a benchmarking over the proposed solutions here is the results http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/ . Fastest is adeneo ;).

Comment: Ah, so speed was your main target... I missed that in your question. I thought you were looking for *fairly easy* ;-)

Comment: I should also note that I have the same results in Chrome, but in FireFox the solution of nnnnn runs consistently faster than adeneo's. In the meanwhile I have [added a faster one](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/1/).

Comment: Thanks all.  Speed is good to have, but I can't sacrifice flexibility for it.  There is the possibility for more than just "test", "run" and "delete", so I can't hardcode those values.  However, there will never be duplicate actions on the same date.  Sorry @nnnnnn I should have specified that.

Comment: @ismail thanks for the benchmarking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ES6 solution, which does not hard-code `test`, `run` or `delete`, but first retrieves all possible actions in the data:

```js
function pivot(list) {
    var actions = list.reduce( (actions, o) => (actions[o.action] = 0, actions), {} );
    var res = list.reduce( (res, o) => ((res[o.date] = res[o.date] || Object.assign({ date: o.date }, actions))[o.action] += o.value, res), {});
    return Object.keys(res).map(key => res[key]);
}

// Sample data
var list = [{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "run",
    "value": 8
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "delete",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 5
}];
// Call
var res = pivot(list);
// Output
console.log(res);
```

If an action value is repeated for the same date the corresponding values are added together (so numerical values are assumed).

#### Alternative focussing on speed

Following the comments on speed, I present here a function that does the job in one loop:

```js
var list = [{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "run",
    "value": 8
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "delete",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 5
}];

function pivot(list) {
    var res = {}, arr = [];
    for (var o of list)
        (res[o.date] || (arr[arr.push(res[o.date] = {
            date: o.date,
            test: 0,
            run : 0,
            "delete": 0
        })-1]))[o.action] += o.value;
    return arr;
}

var res = pivot(list);
console.log(res);
```

I have added this to [the test suit](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/1/) Ismail RBOUH created.

Comment: I've done a benchmarking over the proposed solutions here is the results http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/ . Fastest is adeneo ;).

Comment: I didn't realise you were looking for the fastest solution, so I have added an alternative that focusses on speed, and added it as `trincot_solution2` to your [test suite](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/1/).

Comment: I'm not the OP. I posted a solution and  I was curious about the fastest. +1 good solution.

Comment: Ah yes, I confused you with the OP :-)

Comment: I like the flexible solution, even though it's slower than the hardcode solution it is going to work better for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

This iterates twice to create a map of the dates, then iterates again to insert the missing properties?

```js
var list = [{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "run",
    "value": 8
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "delete",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 5
}];

var map = {};

list.forEach(function(o) {
 if ( !(o.date in map) ) map[o.date] = {};
    map[o.date][o.action] = o.value;
});

var sorted_list = Object.keys(map).map(function(k) {
 return {
     "date"   : k,
     "test"   : (map[k].test || 0),
        "run"    : (map[k].run || 0),
        "delete" : (map[k].delete || 0)
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted_list, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Could also be additive for each property if more than one of each action exists on same day...not sure if that's  possibility or not

Comment: I've done a benchmarking over the proposed solutions here is the results http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/ . Fastest is yours  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using `.reduce()` to create a temporary object to accumulate the values, and then `.map()` to create the final array:

```
var temp = list.reduce(function(c, v) {
  (c[v.date] || (c[v.date]={}))[v.action] = v.value;
  return c;
}, {});
var output = Object.keys(temp).map(function(k) {
  return {
    date : k,
    test : temp[k].test || 0,
    run : temp[k].run || 0,
    "delete" : temp[k].delete || 0
  }
});
```

Comment: I've done a benchmarking over the proposed solutions here is the results http://fiddle.jshell.net/u01kjajc/ . Fastest is adeneo ;).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Underscore solution:

```
var result = _.chain(list).groupBy("date")
.mapObject(function(item, key) {    
    var d = {date: key};
    for(var i in item) d[item[i].action] = item[i].value;
    return d;
}).values().value();
```

```js
var list = [{
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": "2016-05-31",
    "action": "run",
    "value": 8
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "delete",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "action": "test",
    "value": 5
}, ];

var result = _.chain(list).groupBy("date")
.mapObject(function(item, key) { 
    var d = {date: key};
 for(var i in item) d[item[i].action] = item[i].value;
    return d;
}).values().value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```